# Asynchronous polling of endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm a bit stuck on how I would implement a function to poll a certain HTTP endpoint until I get a certain result (i.e. the endpoint updates), but I would like it to send a request every x seconds and when the first one with the 'correct' response comes back, I'd like to halt/throw away every other process and work with the response that I've gotten.

This means that there can be more than one "in flight" request at any given time and I'm not sure how to implement this, i.e. not wait for a response from a prior request before making another request.

I'm using the `request` module which is already async in nature but I'm not sure how i would "fire off" requests every x seconds without waiting on previous ones to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`. Something like this could work:

```
function pollIt() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let done = false;
    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      if(done) {
        return;
      }
      const req = await fetch('/test');
      if(done) {
        return;
      }
      if(req.status === 200) {// assuming HTTP 200 means "OK", could be something else
        done = true;
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve(await req.json());
      }
    }, 1000)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So `await fetch` is the same as using a callback, correct? Also `clearInterval` stops the `setInterval` but there could be other requests that are pending when `clearInterval` is called? Just to clarify.

Comment: yes. the double `if(done)` ensures this thing only returns once, even if two requests return successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
doAgain = true;

function doRequest() {
  request('YOUR END POINT ', function(error, response, body) {
      if (body == "WHAT I WANT IT TO BE") {
        doAgain = false;
        if (doAgain) {
          // DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO
        }
        } else {
          // dont do anything
        }
      });
  }
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (doAgain) {
      doRequest()
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Doesn't that require for the response to come back BEFORE i can check if I need to send a request again? I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like send a request every 100 ms or something, then check for the response once they come back (i.e. not waiting for prior response to send new request)

Comment: `setTimeout` probably should be `setInterval`? And then you also need a `clearInterval` to stop after you've got a successful response.

Comment: `clearInterval` is still missing. You want to stop at some point. Otherwise you'll continue to check `doAgain` every 100ms

Comment: And finally there is still a race condition. two requests may return with the successfull response and enter the `if`. This is especially likely if the server does some kind of long polling

Comment: I hope that does it. Im sorry about my mind being whack today.